# Javascript reference to this does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML/Bootstrap/JS/JQuery code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary confirmAction"
    href="javascript:publicationUuidDelete(this);"
    uuid="da3ad248-3955-4e17-8948-f9247c4e3186">Delete
</a>

function publicationUuidDelete(source) {
    alert($(source).attr("uuid"));
}
```

When I click the hyperlink (button). The alert-window displays 'undefined'.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be using inline event handlers, and you certainly shouldn't be calling JS from a `href` attribute. This wasn't ideal in the 90s and it's certainly not acceptable now. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead, either through [plain JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/click)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting javascript in the href, you should add and event listener to the element.

```js
document.querySelector('.confirmAction').addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(e.target.getAttribute('uuid'));
});
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary confirmAction" href="#"
    uuid="da3ad248-3955-4e17-8948-f9247c4e3186">Delete
</a>
```